# Asus Zen keyboard: Alternative shortcuts for Ctrl Home/Ctrl End

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I need <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys for navigating to the first page/beginning and to the last page/end of a document when proofreading and editing documents in Word. Some documents are very long, but my Asus Zen keyboard doesn't have <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>. I really need an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> for these functions. Advice, please? Thanks!

Comment: What's "Asus Zen keyboard"?

Answer (score 2):

First check your keyboard or manual for instructions. Most small keyboards have a key that doubles as <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> as well as <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> when you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

If not, you will need to re-map the keys to ones you don't use. If you are on Windows follow [this Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052277/accessories-how-do-i-reassign-hot-keys-for-my-keyboard). You basically download their app and change the keys from there.